# ImportError: Twisted requires zope.interface 3.6.0 or later: actually it have been installed

Tags: python, twisted, kivy, zope

I use OSX 10.9 + Kivy 1.9.1, but I have two versions of Python, Mac OSX self-contained 2.7.5 and another standalone 2.7.9 installed. Here are the details:

```
MacBook-Air:wzy$ python
```

> Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
>   [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

```
MacBook-Air:wzy$ python
```

> Python 2.7.9 (v2.7.9:648dcafa7e5f, Dec 10 2014, 10:10:46) 
>   [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

After having installed twisted with `pip install twisted`, I get the following error message in kivy with python 2.7.5, which does not happen in python 2.7.9

```
MacBook-Air:wzy$ kivy
>>> import twisted
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/twisted/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
>     _checkRequirements()
>   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/twisted/__init__.py", line 37, in _checkRequirements
>     raise ImportError(required + ": no module named zope.interface.")
> ImportError: Twisted requires zope.interface 3.6.0 or later: no module named zope.interface.
> ```

```
MacBook-Air:wzy$ python
>>> import twisted
>>> exit()
```

I have even installed zope.interface several times and dedicate install target directory as one of the sys.path of kivy environment.

I do believe this is two version co-exist related, but how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

When you do `pip install twisted`, you are installing Twisted *into* some Python environment, depending on which `python` executable you are invoking `pip` with.  If you have a 2.7.5 environment and a 2.7.9 environment, `pip install` might be putting Twisted in a different place for each, depending on what other options you passed to `pip`.  (You probably passed *some* other options to `pip install` because without privileges, by default, `pip install` will just fail.  Did you do `sudo pip install` perhaps? Did you do `pip install` as an admin user into a homebrewed Python?)

The right way to do this is to only ever install Twisted into virtual environments.  You can create a virtual environment with the `-p` option to `virtualenv`, which tells it which Python to use for that environment.  Then, with the correct virtual environment active, you can `pip install twisted` and everything should work as you expect.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same import error problem, providing another possible solution here:

I have zope.interface 4.4.2 installed, it turned out that my twisted version is too old. By upgrade twisted solved my problem.

`pip install --upgrade twisted`

Comment: I don't understand why this was downvoted, I solved it just like that! My twisted library + dependencies were out of date. Thank you! +1

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Glyph,

Finally I find following simple command could directly fix this problem, because Kivy use his own virtualenv environment, but I do appreciated your kindly help.

*kivy -m pip install twisted*

Best Wish to you,